# Are there any other ways to include JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture, include

We get used to include separately some javascript files with using standard `<script src="file.js"></script>`, but... I really don't like such a way of including.

As for the developer with the C#/C++ background, many features for me are representing as a mess.

I really don't like the way including the js files, but I understand, that it's the most regular practice.

With such kind of thoughts, I suppose to try different possible ways.

As I thought, there are two possible ways, which are able to implement the including process:

1). Create dynamically  tag in imaginary function - `include()`, which I can define in my prototype ( class imitation in js ).

But... It's nearly the same way as the standard including, but just with some dynamic logic stored in prototypes, which may dynamically load some needed modules of web application.

And that's why I dislike it, but it's an option and I must add this to the list.

2). Dynamic load of js file via `AJAX/WebSockets/SPDY`, that you have wanted or even hanlding the parts of the loaded files with the partion function execution (needed some logic or implementing some design patters) with the following execution via `eval()` function and preparing it in the new defined function `include( args );` to make the js scenario looks like:

```
include( "models.js" );
include( "dbController.js" );
...
```

Yes... I know, that `eval()` is an evil in JavaScript world, but I don't know the name of the different function, which allows me the same functionallity.

Also... It may be too slow compared to original way of including and I repeat even vulnerable.

These are the two ways I can imagine, maybe you will suggest a better solution or persuade me from some bad thoughts.

Comment: @Barmar perhaps :) thanks for the link, I shall learn it deeply.

Comment: Closure tools maybe. You can compile all closure compatible code onto one file but still lazy load parts of code that defines behavior that the user is unlikely to use. Many libraries are not compatible with the compiler and will not be compiled with your code though. You need externs for those libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) is a JavaScript modulisation tool that does exactly what you want. You define modules in their own file like so:

```
define('moduleName', [ dependencies ], function () {
  // module code
});
```

And load them asynchronously:

```
require('moduleName');
```

Or as dependencies to other modules:

```
define([ 'moduleName' ], function (myModule) {
   // other module
});
```

It also has an [optimisation tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) which is used to compile your modules into one JavaScript file ready for production.

Comment: Wonderful! +1 thanks a lot for the new information :) Very useful!